# Kafka cluster - separating internal and external communication on running cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

**The case is:** to separate client and broker replication communication + introduce security.

**Question is:** is it possible to separate the communication with some procedure like rolling restart? Without need to have downtime on the whole cluster.

Configuration as is (simple with one port for everything wihout security):

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://server1:9092
```

Wanted configuration (different ports and some with security, replication on 9094 port):

```
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASLPLAIN:SASL_PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=PLAINTEXT://server1:9092,SASLPLAIN://server1,REPLICATION://server1:9094
inter.broker.listener.name=REPLICATION
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

**Progress:**
Configuration below is well working. But only way, without putting cluster into inconsistent state i know now, is to stop the cluster, introduce new configuration as shown above, and start cluster again. That´s obviously not wanted by the customer.
Gratefull for any thoughts how to proceed without need to stop/start whole cluster.

Comment: Wouldn't you want `inter.broker.listener.name=REPLICATION`? And a rolling restart should work fine

Comment: You are right. Thank you.
That´s a mistake in original post. But the problem is, that when you do rolling restart with this config, going from the simple one above, you will basicly get two clusters. 
Brokers with new config will not communicate with new ones.
Also changed SASL mechanism type. Now the post is as it should be.

Comment: We recently did a rolling restart to do exactly this. I didn't watch it get done, but I know it was seemless, though might have taken more than one restart per broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to proceed from original, one listener configuration, to desired by below steps.
If someone has any idea to ease up the process, please add.

Original config:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://server1:9092
```

1.Change server.properties and do rolling restart

```
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASLPLAIN:SASL_PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9093,REPLICATION://SERVER1:9094
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

Also include jaas config as jvm parameter.
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/path/to/kafka_server_jaas.conf

2.Modify the server.properties and do rolling restart

```
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASLPLAIN:SASL_PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9093,REPLICATION://SERVER1:9094
inter.broker.listener.name=REPLICATION
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

3.Modify server properties one last time and do third rolling restart

```
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SASLPLAIN:SASL_PLAINTEXT,REPLICATION:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9092,SASL_PLAINTEXT://SERVER1:9093,REPLICATION://SERVER1:9094
inter.broker.listener.name=REPLICATION
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
```